# Azure Artifacts - Download a specific version of maven artifact

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

We are using azure devops for our CI/CD process. Many a times, in order to do some custom builds, we need to download the specific maven jar from artifact repo.

Is there a way (commandline or API) to do the same ?

Again the question is about download specific jar from azure artifacts.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I am going it to try it today and hope it works for universal packages also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Artifacts - Download a specific version of maven artifact

The answer is yes. We could use the REST API [Maven - Download Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/maven/downloadpackage?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to download the specific jar from azure artifacts:

```
GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/{version}/{fileName}/content?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

First, we need to get the `feedId`. We could use the REST API [Feed Management - Get Feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/get%20feeds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the `feedId`:

```
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

**Note: The project parameter must be supplied if the feed was created in a project. If the feed is not associated with any project, omit the project parameter from the request.**

For other parameters in the URL, we could get it from the overview of the package. Select the package and open the package, we could get following view:

[image]

Now, we have all the parameters, `feedId`, `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, `fileName`.

So, we could use the REST API with `-OutFile $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myFirstApp-1.0-20190818.032400-1.jar` to download the package (Inline powershell task):

```
$url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/_apis/packaging/feeds/83cd6431-16cc-480d-bb4d-a213e17b3a2b/maven/MyGroup/myFirstApp/1.0-SNAPSHOT/myFirstApp-1.0-20190818.032400-1.jar/content?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -OutFile $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myFirstApp-1.0-20190818.032400-1.jar -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get
```

Since my maven feed is an organization scoped feed, I omit the project parameter from the URL.

The result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try it today and hope that it same for universal package also

Comment: Hi Leo. For maven, this is working fine. Can you please how do the same for Universal Package type?

Comment: @Ashutoshgupta, Since this answer resolved your question in this post, please accept it as answer. For the Universal Package type, would you please open a new thread for this question, I will keep follow. One question one thread is recommend. Thanks for your  understanding.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT: I have created the following query for the same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63015550/azure-artifacts-download-a-specific-version-of-universal-artifact

Answer (score 0):

I've found this way:

1. Open **feed** page in Azure, click *Connect to feed*
2. Choose **Maven**, copy the URL from *Project setup* > `repository/url` of the *pom.xml* sample.

   That should look like:

   ```
   https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/YOUR-ORGANIZATION/_packaging/YOUR-FEED-NAME/maven/v1
   ```
3. Append the artifact info to that link:

   ```
   https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/YOUR-ORGANIZATION/_packaging/YOUR-FEED-NAME/maven/v1/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
   ```

   Hint: compare it to the one from maven repository:

   ```
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
   ```