# Azure Artifacts - Download a specific version of Universal artifact

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

We are using azure devops for our CI/CD process. Many a times, in order to do some custom builds, we need to download the specific universal bundle from artifact repo.

Is there a API to do the same ?

Again the question is about downloading a specific version of universal artifact using API or python sdk.

Similar to below question
[Azure Artifacts - Download a specific version of maven artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923061/azure-artifacts-download-a-specific-version-of-maven-artifact)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no API exists to download Universal Package. I've noticed there is already a feature suggestion in the following link, you can vote it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/495533/download-universal-package-trough-api.html

Currently, you must use the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) to download the package. Azure DevOps doesn't support direct HTTP/HTTPS download links or other ways to download the package.

```
az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam --feed FabrikamFiber --name my-first-package --version 1.0.0 --path .
```

More details please refer to the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops#download-a-universal-package