# How to handle Azure Devops 500 MB file size limit (Maven Packages)?

Tags: maven, gradle, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have a 2 GB zip which is now maintained in Nexus as a Maven artifact:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

This zip is fetched by gradle during build time:

```
dependencies {
    packageName("groupId:artifactId:1.0.0@ZIP")
}
```

The zip should now be moved to Azure devops but when I tried to push it there **as Maven artifact** I got an error regarding size.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: progressed file size cannot be greater than size: 2735210496 > 1974413494
If I try to push a smaller sized zip it works as expected.
The command that I use in order to push it as maven artifact is:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging="zip" -DrepositoryId="azureFeed" -Durl="azuremavenRepoURL" -DgroupId="groupId" -DartifactId="artifactId" -Dversion="1.0.0" -Dfile="PathTo2GBFile\FileName.ZIP"
```

After investigations I found the documentation mentioning maven packages size limit:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/limits?view=azure-devops

**How can I push my zip as a Maven artifact in Azure Devops since it is bigger than 500 MB ?**
**What is the easiest way of pushing the 2GB zip to Azure Devops so that this will be easily fetched by Gradle (like it is working now with Nexus) ?**

PS: I have tried and succeeded pushing the 2GB zip as an Universal Package(using az CLI) but in that case I am not able to fetch the zip in gradle.
More than that, from what I was able to find, fetching Universal Packages through API is not yet possible in Azure Devops: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/495533/download-universal-package-trough-api.html,
[Azure Artifacts - Download a specific version of Universal artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63015550/azure-artifacts-download-a-specific-version-of-universal-artifact)

Comment: What kind of artifact is that? 2 GB size? Based on the given maven snipped that's weird...

Comment: How do you produce such a large artifact?

Comment: I have just added in the question the mvn command that I used for trying to produce and push my artifact to Azure

Comment: The zip contains the platform on top of which the project is build(that is why it is so big). I do not argue that keeping it as a maven artifact is a little bit weird. But I guess that storing it like this on Nexus made the fetching via Gradle really easy, as fetching any other maven dependency... . If this can be stored in any other way on Azure Artifacts I am fine with it as long as Gradle can fetch in a way or another...

Answer (score 1):

> How to handle Azure Devops 500 MB file size limit (Maven Packages)?

Just as know, there is a 500MB size limit for the Maven packages per file, and also no REST API to download the Universal Packages at this moment.

We could only use use the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) to download the package. Azure DevOps doesn't support direct HTTP/HTTPS download links or other ways to download the package：

```
az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam --feed FabrikamFiber --name my-first-package --version 1.0.0 --path .
```

You could check this document [Download a Universal Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops#download-a-universal-package) for some more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I did not know about the Gradle Download Task... But since Azure DevOps doesn't support direct HTTP/HTTPS download links I suppose I cannot download my universal package using the Gradle Download Task, right ?

Comment: @dj_frunza, Yes, you are right! This suggestion is indeed inappropriate and I will remove it from my answer. So, how about use the Azure CLI to download the package? It can download the package, but I am not 100% sure whether it is suitable for your situation.

Comment: I need the download to automatically work on multiple machines(having different OS) easily. Fetching it from Azure using Gradle as Maven dependency requires just a secure token and that is why I wanted to do it like this. I think that Azure CLI is more cumbersome since it implies installing it on all machines and besides from that, Azure CLI requires also user and password in order to login and I would like to avoid maintaining a lot of passwords on multiple system

Comment: @dj_frunza, According to your description, Gradle is more suitable for you. But I don't know enough about Gradle, I haven't encountered Gradle that can handle Universal Package. This will be a hindrance

Comment: Ok, no problem, thank you for the support you gave me so far